# Error in using group by in firebird 1

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to run the following query but it is not working!

```
select extract(month from flight_date_time) mnt from T_PEREXOD where extract( year from flight_date_time)='2012'
group by mnt 
order by mnt
```

I tried also subquerying

```
select mnt from (select extract(month from flight_date_time) AS mnt from T_PEREXOD)
group by mnt
order by mnt
```

but it pops out an error 
Invalid token.

```
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, char 18.
select.
```

Is that a problem of Firebird version 1 ??

How about making groupping work without any views, procedures, computed fields and so on ? 'cause I don't like to alter that database !

Answer (score 3):

First - Extract returns a smallint or decimal value so your where clousure is wrong.

Second - Subqueries are supported from 1.5 up

Try changing `SELECT EXTRACT(...) as mnt` (add as) in your first query or try to use column index grouping like

> GROUP BY 1
>
> ORDER BY 1

Firebird 1.0 sql conformance is something you might be interesting in but this is the only one I can find:
http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/sql-conformance/

If you have any opportunity I advise updating to latest release of FB

Comment: Also tried `select extract(month from flight_date_time) AS mnt from T_PEREXOD
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1` but Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, char 10.
1.

Comment: @SuhrobSamiev Yes, it's a very good idea. You shouldn't have any problems with 2.5

Comment: Best performance ever seen with ver 1 )) Query is working cooool !

Comment: Some slides for migration that someone find it usefull http://www.slideshare.net/ibsurgeon/firebird-migration-from-firebird-15-to-firebird-25